# Flowcharting 2 methods that use the same variable

Tags: algorithms, flowchart

[image]

so I need to flowchart something similar to the picture. 
The the first flowchart on left and the 2 flowcharts on the right is on different classes.

The someClass have a instance variable named MyVar and 2 methods named setMethod and getMethod.
The getMethod and setMethod uses the instance variable myVar how would I show that in a flowchart? or is flowchart above acceptable? and where will I place the declaration of myVar?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with this kind of diagramming.  Just write the code; the code says the same thing, but without having to draw all of the circles, lines and arrowheads.

Comment: I wouldn't too but my teacher requires a flowchart of the code of our program

Answer (score 1):

Flowcharts don't provide standard means for declaring or accessing variables, and they have no elements which directly relate to a specific programming language. One is free to put any kind of description into the boxes as long as the description matches the related step.

So if you are using an OO programming language which provides things like classes or instance variables, feel free to put those elements into the boxes, using the syntax of the language (assumed your teacher did not gave you more specific instructions).

Note also flowcharts are from the ancient past of programming, where they were an improvement over pure assembly code. Citing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart):

> popularity decreased in the 1970s, when interactive computer terminals and third-generation programming languages became common tools for computer programming, since algorithms can be expressed more concisely as source code in such languages

So in the context of a modern programming language, flowcharts seem to be an anachronism today, especially for such trivial examples like getting or setting a variable they look heavily oversized.